# Global replacement of string value in Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a rather unique situation where I have been asked to make a web version of a desktop product with an existing database.  The problem is the previous developer of the product put a # in a string when it was empty on saving a record so the database has tables filled with a # in almost all string type columns.  He had a function that stripped this out when referencing any field so that the #'s weren't displayed (begs the question as to why he even included them!!)

My problem is I want to be able to use ASP.Net, Entity Framework, Models etc so I can simply return the model or IEnumerables of the model in Web Api, but simply doing this alone will mean textboxes will end up with a # in them.

Rather than having to create a function of some kind on either client or server side, can anyone advise a possible way to globally replace the # with a blank value throughout the sql server database or advise any other possible solutions that come to mind?

Comment: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_search_and_replace.htm

Comment: I modified the above which has worked ok but I couldn't include ntext types, is there a variation of the above I can use for those?

Comment: You only have to find a value and set a new value. Doesn't require Replace.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use an update script to convert "#" to NULL or something else:

```
update dbo.X
set Value1 = NULL
when Value1 = '#'
```

It would probably be a larger effort, but would be one-time, and worth it to make things easier for your future development.

Outside of that, there is nothing implicit to EF or .NET that would strip these out automatically; you would need to write a routine to do it.  EF can make that more of a pain, because you can't use a custom routine in a LINQ query that it's going to translate to SQL.

Comment: Issue is there are many tables and only need to check string type fields.  If I wrote the script manually it would take weeks, any suggestions on a script that will loop all tables and certain field types?

Comment: You could try to leverage INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS views which contain all of the metadata from there.  One trick I would use is use a select statement to query the update statements as in `select 'update dbo.' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = NULL where ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''#'''`.  Something like that.  Unfortunately, this is the repercussions of certain design decisions...